# Python: How to use threads in network?

Tags: python, multithreading, networking

I am trying to make a program that will search random ids for
site titles. I made a one threaded function but it is super slow
because it has to wait for timeout if there is no server at random
ip. I have no knowledge of threads can someone help me? Any good 
tutorials on threads? Or maybe an example on how to have a main thread
of ips and another few threads checking ips.

Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Could you add some pieces of code, it would be easier to help you.

Comment: I have a method generateIp that returns public id and check which takes that ip and returns contents of title tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I typed up a very simple example and hope it will be a good starter for you:

```
# this is important
from thread import start_new_thread, allocate_lock

# this is for show
from time import sleep
from random import randint

# global receiver
myresults = []
counter = 0

# lock that protects "myresults"
lock = allocate_lock()

#lock that protects "counter"
lock2 = allocate_lock()

# this does the url processing
def retrieve(url):
    # sleep for 4-10s to simulate processing time
    sleep(randint(4,10))
    print "Done handling %s" % url

# thread safe retrieve
def retrieveLocking(url):
    // global variables
    global myresults, counter

    // random processing time
    sleep(randint(4,10))
    print "[LOCKING] Done handling %s" % url

    // request access to myresults' lock
    lock.acquire()
    myresults.append(url)
    lock.release() // release lock!

    // request access to counter's lock
    lock2.acquire()
    counter += 1
    lock2.release() // release lock!

# here goes your main loop
start_new_thread(retrieve, ("A",))
start_new_thread(retrieve, ("B",))
start_new_thread(retrieve, ("C",))

# using locking
start_new_thread(retrieveLocking, ("A",))
start_new_thread(retrieveLocking, ("B",))
start_new_thread(retrieveLocking, ("C",))
```

Handling the results of your queries can in this case be done by a global variable. There are more complex ways to retrieve data from threads tho'.

If you go with the global variable solution, I added locks. In concurrent programming "race conditions" can occur, when several threads want to access the same resource at the same time. To prevent overwriting old states of those variables, a lock can protect that resource. Only after the lock is released the next thread is allowed to access the resource. Waiting for a release is taken care of for you here :)

I hope this helps :)

// EDIT:
If you solve your problem in this way, there is not really a way to determine if all threads terminated. Hence, if you want to stick to this solution, add a counter that is increased by each thread (protect the counter with a lock) and do a busy-wait (endless loop until the counter is reached). This is really **bad practice**. However, if you want to code things out more elaborately, things will become a bit more complicated and I assume that you are new to  concurrent programming:

```
while True:
    lock2.acquire()
    if counter == totalthreads: # in this case 3
        lock2.release()
        break
    lock2.release()
print "Done! %r" % myresults
```

Comment: Ok, how do i make it infinite? just answer this and you get the best answer. Please i dont understand threads

Comment: As you know how many threads you will spawn, add a global counter. Whenever a thread is done processing (like when its ready to append to the list and acquires the lock), increase that counter. At the end of the code loop until the count is reached. But I want to mention again that this is easy but **bad practice** :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay so basically you want to have a script running that spawns a couple of threads, where each thread tryies to reach an ip right ?

Spawning a thread is really easy:

```
import threading
thread = threading.Thread(target=target_function, args(argument1, argument2,...))  
thread.start()
```

In this case target_function should be your ip checking function.

There are a few way's of how threads can report their results back to the main thread. I'm guessing that this is supposed to be a simple script that won't be used very often so why not simply use a dict where you use the ips as keys and the result as value.